# Whitelisting asp.net bundles

Tags: iis-7.5, bundling-and-minification, whitelist

IIS has a default blacklist of filetypes that won't be served to the users of its sites, some of those types are: .asax, .cs, .vb, .config.
You can find the setting in the *Features View* under *Request Filtering*.

I did a powershell query to find all of the filetypes in my website, and whitelisted only the filetypes I want IIS to serve:

```
Get-Childitem . | WHERE { -NOT $_.PSIsContainer } | Group Extension -NoElement | Sort Count -Desc > FileExtensions.txt
```

Now the sites works perfect and secure, until I enable ASP.Net bundling. 404's will occur on the bundled styles and scripts, as those are not whitelisted.

Now the question: can I whitelist bundled files and what extension should be added to the *Allowed Extensions* list in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can ;-). 
Just add the correct extention to the bundle name.

e.g.: ~/Bundles/Styles => ~/Bundles/Styles.css

Change in RegisterBundles() method and in Styles.Render() and you are done

Comment: That does the trick indeed, now.. why didn't I think of that! Thanks Andre!